# min-height:100% won't work as i want it too

Tags: html, height, css

I have a container div, conteining 3 divs, a sidebar, a content and a header while all the elements inside are rendered as they should (they are positioned as "relative" if this may influence in my problem), the sidebar and the content render `min-height: 100%` as I need, the div containing them won't adapt to those 3 elements, acting like `overflow: visible`, while I don't want the content to overflow, I want the whole page to scroll and the div to adapt to the content size...

I tried to put my code here : http://jsfiddle.net/vhZV6/

I also cut out some of the graphical tweeks wich should not influence at all... here is a screen of my problem too:

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/217/problemrt.jpg/]

I don't need old broweser integration on this matter (as IE 5/6).

Comment: Have you tried adding `overflow:auto;` to your `.container` div?

Comment: OMG! this solved the whole problem! you are a genius, may i ask for some further help on the matter? as you can see, i had to set Height:100% on the body&&html but what i really wanted wasn't it to give me the height of the Browser Visible area, i instead wanted the html(and body too) to have the length of the full stretched contenet, min-height on body & html won't solve this... any help? thx a whole lot again ^^

Comment: Hmmm, let me post the above as an answer so you can accept it and then you should post the question from your comment as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `overflow:auto;` to your `.container` div.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp <--- this page actually state that when you put overflow:auto, the content scrolls down, is it just a bad info, or it is how it acts on some browser?
thx again for the solution ^^

Comment: Don't ever go by w3schools. They have some useful information but that also have plenty of old, outdated, or plain inaccurate info as well. Use MDN instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this.  'height: auto' is no longer set once any of the height elements are messed with.

```
min-height:100% !important;
height:auto !important;
```

Comment: this didn't change anything, it just keep behavin as before (i put it inside both the container and the content)

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple problem: your inner divs are floating. The solution is very simple, just add to your css the following (this is the best solution whenever you have floating divs):

```
.container:before { 
    content:".";
    display:block;
    height:0;
    clear:both;
    visibility:hidden; 
}
```

Comment: overflow:auto; solved my problem, may i ask some more indeep explanation of this solution you just gave me? like the ":before" part, i never saw that, alsto what's the content:"." propriety ? thanks again for your time ^^

Comment: The :before selector inserts content before the content of the selected element. The :after selector inserts content after the content of the selected element.  Content: "." makes sure that the "div" inserted before your container will be interpreted by any browser, because you have 0 height.