# min-height:100% won't apply on a nested div

Tags: html, height, css

I have a container div, containing 3 divs, a sidebar, a content and a header while all the elements inside are rendered as they should (they are positioned as "relative" if this may influence in my problem), the sidebar and the content won't render *`min-height: 100%;`* no matter what...

my div won't stretch with the min-height as it is supposed to...

here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/vhZV6/4/

as you can see (I put a white background to best recognize it) the div wich is supposed to stretch simply won't...

Edit: here is a temp site where I tried to implement the solutions... http://www.wabisuke-team.org/Temp/home.html as you can see, all but the last 2 pages (strees and "contattateci") are rendered as they should, but those 2 while have a messed background image out of the div not resizing as it should...

Edit:
I solved this by putting a min-height in pixels, instead of in percentage, it now works as i wanted it to, thanks everyone for your efforts and for you patience ^^

Comment: is this question different than this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534787/min-height100-wont-work-as-i-want-it-too ?

Comment: yep, it is for the same site, but it's a different matter, what i missed there was overflow:auto, but the style as i wanted it to be rendered only actual work when i have some content wich really overflow, if by chance my content is less then the "body height:100%" the background image on the div will be cutted off, and the div won't actually apply min-height:100%...

Comment: just add 5 characters to the top of your css. `s/html/html,body/`

Comment: like so:[link](http://jsfiddle.net/vhZV6/19/) ? i don't think this is what i needed? i mean, it doesn't render as i need...

Comment: hehehe s/A/B mean switch A with B - so try this :P (sorry that made me actually laugh out loud :D) http://jsfiddle.net/vhZV6/20/

Comment: If you don't already know this: percentage height/width values are based on their direct parent. So if you have a child element with a % value for height/width that childs direct parent needs a defined height/width value as well.

Comment: sorry for the s/A/B it's the first time for me seeing this... also if i have 3 elemente nested in each other, and only the outer one have a set height/width, can't both the nested one have a percentage width height? (if so, can the outer just be html?) i will edit my question with some image to make what i needed to accomplish more clear (user already found the answear)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

here is the fiddle with long content http://jsfiddle.net/xM4NC/

and here is with short http://jsfiddle.net/xM4NC/1/

I set body to height 100%, but the content div to min-height 100%. That way it's parent had a defined height, so that div will be at least as tall as the body, but will grow beyond it if necessary. Then added a left margin and floated the sidebar in that space

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    background: #EEE;
    border-left: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 180px;
    font: 1.5em arial, verdana, sans-serif;
    width: 960px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="header">header</div>
<div class="sidebar1">sidebar</div>
<div id="content">
    text
</div>​
```

Comment: this is actually what i need it to do, and i tought about using javascript too, but i would like to keep this matter as simple as possible, both because my other pages are loeaded with javascript and i would not like to add some other code if i don't strictly must and because i have no experience with jquery (i use the standar javascript with dom implementation...) is this the only way to get what i want?

Comment: @YuriCollector'sEditionRossi don't use js for this.. that would be plain stupid. "Lets bring a dump truck to move an anthill"

Comment: I've edited the answer, take a look at the css only approach.

Comment: I set body to height 100%, but the content div to min-height 100%.  That way it's parent had a defined height, so that div will be at least as tall as the body, but will grow beyond it if necessary.  Then added a left margin and floated the sidebar in that space.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the changes.  Hope it works for you.

Comment: okay, this is plain weird, i tried to implement this solution and nothing changed by the version i had before, so i tried mozilla element inspector to check if the div min-height was parsed at all or not, the actual parsed min-height is 815px, but it is still rendered as a height size that only fit the content... what am i doing wrong? should i put everything online so you can have a better view at my source/codes/overall site ?

Comment: Notice how the html is formatted, I have the header and sidebar outside of the content div, as siblings rather than children.  If that's not it then yes either seeing the source or putting it in a jsfiddle would help

Comment: in my code sidebar, header, and content are sibiling all under the parent "Conteiner" whose parent is "body", Conteiner height is set as : `height:auto !important;`... i'm uploading a temp version of the site, it's taking a while, i will post it as soon as it is ready... i edited my question to include images wich should show how it is formatted...

Comment: i added the site, so you can see the full source and the full styling, that won't do btw, because by switching container height to 100% the other pages will have a messed background or will get 2 scroll bars... (even if i add overflow:auto;)

Comment: try this link here, it's a different approach, it's just the one page but you get the idea http://lifeguardit.com/manga/

Comment: basically you put the background on the container instead of the content? i had it like this before, but since i wanted the image to fit just the content i went trough the hell of finding this problem solution... well i guess i should just put it like this, thanks for your time and your efforts ^^

Comment: If you set body to height: 100% and the container to min-height 100% this will work. The problem is min-height is not an explicit declaration of height. So content cannot use height 100%. Plus the content's height should not be 100% of container, it should really be 100% of container - header height.  So unless you are will to adjust the structure of the html javascript is going to be the best method of increasing the height of the content div.

Answer (score 1):

Use height: 100%, there is no need for min-height  see here http://jsfiddle.net/vhZV6/5/

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
body {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow:auto;
    /* just some back ground and graphical tweeks*/

    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#000000;
    background: #86acef; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #86acef 0%, #baceef 35%, #86acef 70%, #baceef 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#86acef), color-stop(35%,#baceef), color-stop(70%,#86acef), color-stop(100%,#baceef)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #86acef 0%,#baceef 35%,#86acef 70%,#baceef 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #86acef 0%,#baceef 35%,#86acef 70%,#baceef 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #86acef 0%,#baceef 35%,#86acef 70%,#baceef 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #86acef 0%,#baceef 35%,#86acef 70%,#baceef 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#86acef', endColorstr='#baceef',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

}
/* ~~this fixed width container surrounds the other divs~~ */
.container {
    height: 100%;
    container:overflow;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #FFF url(../img/Graphic/bg.jpg) no-repeat  fixed center;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-position:center;
    margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout */
}
.header {
    position:relative;
    /* header graphical tweeks */

    background: #2945c4; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #2945c4 0%, #7db9e8 35%, #2945c4 70%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#2945c4), color-stop(35%,#7db9e8), color-stop(70%,#2945c4), color-stop(100%,#7db9e8)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #2945c4 0%,#7db9e8 35%,#2945c4 70%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #2945c4 0%,#7db9e8 35%,#2945c4 70%,#7db9e8 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #2945c4 0%,#7db9e8 35%,#2945c4 70%,#7db9e8 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #2945c4 0%,#7db9e8 35%,#2945c4 70%,#7db9e8 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#2945c4', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.sidebar1 {
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    width: 180px;
    height:100%;
}
.content {
    position:relative;
    padding: 10px 0;
    width: 780px;
    float: left;
    height:100%;
    background: #FFF;
    background-size:100% 100%;
    background-position:center;
}
​
```

Comment: this solution won't do, if i apply this solution (wich works fine by itself on low content pages) it will mess my high content page layout, basically i can't put `height:100%;` on the body, otherwhise some of my background will just not show... what i need is a style wich will grant me a minimum height of 100%, but will stretch out the body, the content, the cointeiner and the sidebar to fit the content of my pages if it goes over that 100% mark...